# nginx error when server responds too soon (I think)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-ingress, node-streams

Using `ingress-nginx` in a `kubernetes` cluster in front of a `Node.js` server running `express`.

Getting this error:
`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`

In this scenario:

1. The server is processing a small-ish file (60kb) upload, as a node `stream` (i.e. in `express` terms it's `pipeline`ing the `req` (`Request`) that's passed in as the first argument of the route handler).
2. While processing the file, an error is thrown near the beginning (maybe 4-5k in), and a `400` response is sent on the spot.
3. The nginx ingress proxy gives a `502` to the client and the logs show the error above.

The reason I believe the error may be due to the server sending back a response before the entire request is read:

1. When I cut down the input file to end right after the place that causes the error, the nginx error goes away and the client gets the `400` from the server as I'd expect.
2. The same error-handling code works fine in other cases in which the request is fully read i.e. when using `req.body` and not streaming the request body.
3. When the file is corrected and doesn't throw errors, everything is great and `200` is returned, so it's not a timeout (like a lot of the results when searching for this nginx error) or something along those lines.

I'd like to find a way to fix the error without ugly workarounds in the code, but I'm open to anything. My thoughts were some `ingress-nginx` annotation that makes it handle the "premature response end" properly, or a way on the node side to consume the stream (even though I don't really want to and don't feel I should have to) before sending back the error, to make nginx happy. Or open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As I waited hopefully for an answer here, the days passed and my hope grew dim. I spent a while playing with it some more and came up with an "ugly workaround in the code" as I mentioned in my question.

In case this might help someone in the future:

I wrapped the input stream by reading it into a buffer/string and then re-streaming it, and this fixed the problem. This will obviously only be a solution if you can afford to read the entire input into memory - I could so it's all good, but if you can't, I don't know what you can do to avoid this error.

```
async (input) => {
    const chunks = [];
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        input.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
        input.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        input.on('end', () => resolve());
    });
    return Readable.from([Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8')]);
}
```